# Setting a value to an arbitrary key at genesis?

Tags: storage, frame, genesis

I am wondering if it is possible to set a value to an arbitrary storage key at genesis.

Let's say I want to populate the key `0x3fba98689ebed1138735e0e7a5a790abee99a84ccbfb4b82e714617e5e06f6f7` at genesis, but this key is not part of any `GenesisConfig` of any pallet I have installed in my runtime.

Is there a way to work around this ?

Comment: The key I have chosen for the question is not the concrete key I am trying to mutate, is just an example.

Comment: I think you can edit the genesis spec file. What is your use-case? When do you need the insertion to happen?

Comment: Indeed, editing the spec file was my first idea.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert the key/value into `chain_spec["genesis"]["raw"]["top"]`.

This is what Subalfred does to fork off the chain https://github.com/hack-ink/subalfred/blob/3994cfe31dd13d3aaf757503da3e73afd186c319/src/subalfred/core/state/fork_off.rs#L142.

Comment: Yeah, this was my first go to and I couldn't make it work. I guess I might have done something wrong, will give it a go again. Thanks

Comment: You could follow https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/storage-key.html to calculate the correct storage key.

Comment: This is not a problem, ty though :)